# Get this Range slider working on touch

Tags: javascript, input, range, touch, uislider

I have [this rangeslider](https://nlcoli-levonovka.savviihq.com) but it doesn't work on touch devices... Does someone know why?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: Please read this: [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: So just paste the whole html, js and css here?